# Can not perform cast when running method asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've encountered a weird problem while experimenting with async programming. 
Here's a part of my method that behaves weirdly:

```
List<HtmlElement> links1 = new List<HtmlElement>();
links1.AddRange(w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a").Cast<HtmlElement>());
```

When I used to call it synchronously it worked fine. But when I call it asynchronously it throws the "system.invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid".
The event I'm calling it from looks like that:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = Task.Run(() => util.handleBrowser(webBrowser1));
}
```

Couldn't google anything relevant.. Any ideas would be appreciated!

P.S.: If I run it like that, will the util.handleBrowser method be able to fire the same event a second time by using webBrowser1.Navigate() ?

Comment: What was the description of the Exception?

Comment: system.invalidcastexception specified cast is not valid. Updated the question.

Comment: Useful tool when debugging async issues is the Exception breakpoint: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx

Comment: You could add a select lambda before the cast and put a breakpoint on the callback, to see why type is coming back.

Comment: James, I know that `w.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")` returns `HtmlElementCollection`, and `List.AddRange()` accepts `IEnumerable<HtmlElement>`. And cast was mending the problem just fine until I ran the thing with Task.Run.

Comment: From your description I would venture a guess that the document is not fully loaded yet. That is why it behaves fine synchronisticly but not when asynchronistic

Comment: Just because you're doing it asynchronously doesn't make casts somehow invalid.  You're probably looking in the wrong castle.

Comment: DaniDev, that's the point! The event that calls the function is fired when and only when the browser is finished loading the document. And the unloaded elements wouldnt make it in the `GetElementsByTagName()` anyway.

Comment: Will, That is precisely the problem. I know for a fact that everything I listed in a description is all that happens in the program until the exception. I've run and rerun debug, used tools Gus suggested - nothing relevant came up. It's like this method is not meant for async performance. Ugh,